# Get type of class from a static method

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I have a template class with a static method, ideally I would like to add to this method something like this `std::cout << decltype(this) << std::endl;` but this doesn't compile since I can not use `this` inside a static method. I found a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524335/is-there-any-way-to-convert-decltype-to-string-in-a-macro) (not sure I can print `decltype` output) but it also uses `this` so I can not use it inside the static method. I was forced to use it inside the constructor, but I didn't give up yet. Does anyone has an idea how to print the class type inside a static method?

Comment: What is this even supposed to mean?! `decltype` denotes a *type*. What is `cout << int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(C).name() << std::endl;
    }

};

int main() {
    C<int>::print();
    C<char>::print();
    return 0;
}
```